# Cycles texture bake differs from rendered appearence?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

Baking textures in cycles in ruining the look of objects, but it only seems to be a problem when scaling is required(Scaling in this case was done in UV Editor by scaling UV unwrap. Leaving unwrap oversized causes texture display problems, but if I try to use Ctrl+a to average size and then Ctrl+P to pack, that causes issues in its own right.  Node Setup Included.  Im sure there is something simple I am overlooking, but I can't seem to nail it down. [image: NodeSetup][image: RenderedBeforeBake][image: BlenderTextureAfterBaking][image: TextureAfterBakeinUnity] Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have two UV maps? One for the original cycles material, and then a nicer one for the baked textures? Also, when you bake textures, you need to have a texture node in the node tree that holds the texture that you want to bake to. This node can't be connected to anything.

Comment: (I know this is old, but if you are still interested in an answer..) Is it possible you have multiple UV maps? If not, is scale applied?